# What is "PHP-standardized" version number strings?

Tags: php

I searched for a web resource that describes "PHP-standardized" version number strings but i didn't find, is there one?

I want to know how to write a valid "PHP-standardized" version.

Comment: what do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Check http://php.net/version_compare for what PHP actually does with version strings

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I think OP wants a description of what a _"PHP-standardized" version_ looks like. I can't find it either.

Comment: If I have got you correct are you looking to compare PHP versions?

Comment: Define ""PHP-standardized" version". Do you mean the versioning scheme of php itself or projects written in php?

Comment: I know about version_compare function. Its page says "compares two PHP-standardized version number strings", so my question is: What is the PHP-standardized version number strings? What is the format of that standard string? Isn't there any page describes this standard? How to tell if some version string is a valid PHP-standardized or not? based on what? The reference, that what I search for.

Comment: The function version_compare('5.2', '5.2.0') returns -1 means version 5.2.0 is greater than 5.2 which isn't logic to me, they are supposed to be the same version! so i guess the standard tells: don't add the right zero, so i wondered what is the full standard?

Comment: Do you mean this http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php?

Answer (score 0):

`PHP-standardized number format` that is pertain to describing page is [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), in my opinion, as I didn't find any official information in manual.

You need to provide zero, on **X** position ( last one - see semantic versioning), as you can see at.

Function `phpversion()` return all 3 position.